# Subdivision surface

Tags: subdivision-surface

For some reason I'm not getting any good result trying to make sharp cut on subdivided object
Here's the situation.
Shape is otherwise round but the edge should be without smoothing
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the crease of different edge to make the edges sharper
[image: creases]